# How to get the image of vimeo video?

Tags: video, vimeo, vimeo-api

How to get the image of the vimeo video. We can get the image of youtube video by using their api. How the same can be done in Vimeo case?

I need this because I want to pin(share) this vimeo video on pinterest and pinterest allows only images in its url.

Or if there are some other way to pin vimeo video in pinterest please suggest me! And help and suggestion would be appreciated.

[Vimeo video link](http://vimeo.com/95235223)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For private videos you will need to use their API : https://developer.vimeo.com/api/start

For public videos you can just use oEmbed : https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed

Comment: thankyou this is exectly I was looking for. XML link gives the right jpg but json dosn't. I will use XML. thankyou again.

Comment: Which video id behaves that way? You should see the same image with both systems.